# Sampling problem: How to remove a sample from another sampling in an iteration of samples so its only selected once

Tags: python, sampling

I have two dictionaries:

```
providers_lists = 
 {'PCP1': ['member2', 'member26', 'member6', 'member9'],
 'PCP2': ['member10', 'member18', 'member2', 'member26', 'member7'],
 'PCP4': ['member10','member13','member25', 'member27', 'member5','member7','member9'],
 'PCP5': ['member13', 'member25', 'member5', 'member6', 'member9'],
 'PCP6': ['member18', 'member27', 'member5']}

 providers = Counter({'PCP1': 2, 'PCP2': 1, 'PCP4': 2, 'PCP5': 1, 'PCP6': 2})
```

I want to sample from each provider's list of potential members in `providers_lists` by randomly sampling the number of open slots per provider ('PCP') as seen in `provider_counts`.  And those that are sampled win the spot with that provider.

The problem is, a "member" may appear more than once in the iteration since they have more than one choice, but they should only be matched once.  If they are selected once, they shouldnt be selected again.  How do I create this condition? Alter an object after each iteration?

What I have so far is:

```
# Randomly sample out a member
new_matched = dict()
for k, v in providers.items():
    new_matches[k] = random.sample(providers_lists[k], v)

new_matches = 
{'PCP1': ['member26', 'member2'],
 'PCP2': ['member10'],
 'PCP4': ['member9', 'member27'],
 'PCP5': ['member25'],
 'PCP6': ['member27', 'member18']}
```

Obviosly the results will look different each time this is run, but as you can see for example, "member27" appears twice but I would like so once chosen they are out of another of the other sample populations.  Thanks

Comment: A simple way is just to produce a new sample if one contains duplicate members. Here duplicate members should occur more the every 7th sample (occurence of member27 in PCP4 which will conflict with the one in PCP6) but probably less than every 5th. If you try to modify the providers list, you could change the probability distribution (if you remove member27 from PCP4 it is was chosen in PCP6) or fall in a dead end (if you chose member 27 from PCP4 and then try to remove it from PCP6)

Comment: @SergeBallesta Thank you.  Do you think you could provide with a sample code snippet of how you would resample if it contains a duplicate?

Comment: Assuming that you already have a function `do_make_sample` to generate a sample, it could be `def make_sample(*args, **kwargs): while True: smpl = do_make_sample(*args, **kwargs); members = set([i for lst in smpl.values() for i in lst]; if len(members) == 8: return smpl` where the colons (`:`) and semicolons (`;`) delimit lines, and the semicolons should not be kept.

Comment: Where did you get 8 from?

Comment: The total number of members when there is no duplicate: `sum(providers.values())`.